# Get Spark (DataFrame) Schema at run-time (from Avro schema)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, avro

My use-case is to consume Avro messages (via Kafka) and process them. There are different topics for different *kind* of messages. To account for Avro schema evolution, I cannot provide static Spark schema (derived from Avro schema) to `createDataFrame` method. This is how the current code structure looks like

```
def avro_decoder(value):
  avro_schema_id, message = serializer.decode_message(value)
  return avro_schema_id, message

def process_rdd(time, rdd, **schema**):
  if rdd.isEmpty():
    return
  df = spark_session.createDataFrame(
         rdd.map(lambda (k, (avro_schema_id, event): event),
         **schema**)

kafka_dstream = KafkaUtils.createStream(streaming_context,
                                        zkQuorum,
                                        "spark-streaming-consumer",
                                        {topic: 1},
                                        valueDecoder=avro_decoder)
kafka_dstream.foreachRDD(
        lambda time, rdd: write_parquet_file(time, rdd, 
        **spark_schema**))
```

I want to get rid of (hardcoded) `schema` argument to method `process_rdd`. Since I have `avro_schema_id` present with the message, I should be able to convert it to spark struct schema and use that in `createDataFrame` method. But the problem is, as you can guess, `avro_schema_id` is inside RDD and without computing RDD its value cannot be used. Computing whole RDD (before actual DataFrame processing) doesnt make sense.

Is there any (efficient) way to achieve this?